# VK api ошибка 100 100. One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Бот должен пересылать личное сообщение от одного пользователя другому. Простое сообщение отправляется без каких-либо ошибок. 
А вот ошибка заключается, в том, что сервер не отправляет приложение к сообщению (в моем случае это фотография). Примечательно, что это зависит от того, с какой страницы отправляется запрос - если это та страница, с которой был выдан ключ-доступа к сообщениям, то все нормально работает и картинка пересылается, а вот со всех остальных страниц - нет. То есть проблема вряд ли должна быть связана с кодом, скорее всего с какими-то правами. API используется последнее, самое актуальное. Вот код ошибки целиком

100. One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: message is empty or invalid. request_params = {'v':
     '5.103', 'method': 'messages.send', 'oauth': '1', 'random_id': '0', 'attachment':
     'photo582248194_457239051_63093a408ca6ab8d48', 'user_id': 'мой айди'}

```
    message = str(data['message']['text'])
    if data['message']['attachments']==[]:
        attachment = []
    else:
        attach = data['message']['attachments'][0]
        attach_type = attach['type']
        attachment = "{0}{1}_{2}_{3}".format(
            attach_type,
            attach[attach_type]['owner_id'],
            attach[attach_type]['id'],
            attach[attach_type]['access_key']
        )
    # Отправка
    vkapi.send_message(user_id, token, message, attachment)
```

Может быть у кого-то была похожая проблема? Поддержка вк не отвечает нормально)
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Покажите каким модулем вы пользуетесь для vkapi

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации вк](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send), в поле attachment нужно помещать строку такого формата:

`<type><owner_id>_<media_id>`, а вы перемещаете туда строку формата

`<type><owner_id>_<media_id>_<access_key>`

Пример правильного поля attachment: 
`photo582248194_457239051`

То есть attachment должен выглядит примерно так:

```
attachment = "{0}{1}_{2}".format(
    attach_type,
    attach[attach_type]['owner_id'],
    attach[attach_type]['id']
)
```

Answer (score -1):

attachment должен быть строкой. Замените в условии attachment = [], на attachment = ''

```py
    message = str(data['message']['text'])
    if data['message']['attachments']==[]:
        attachment = ''
    else:
        attach = data['message']['attachments'][0]
        attach_type = attach['type']
        attachment = "{0}{1}_{2}_{3}".format(
            attach_type,
            attach[attach_type]['owner_id'],
            attach[attach_type]['id'],
            attach[attach_type]['access_key']
        )
    # Отправка
    vkapi.send_message(user_id, token, message, attachment)
```

У вас если data['message']['attachments']==[], то переменная attachment = [], это список, а должна быть строкой. Ниже вы передаете ее в качестве аргумента в vkapi.send_message(user_id, token, message, attachment), хотя как сказано в документации, тип должен быть строкой!